# Is there a way to get a users Bitmoji using Access tokens from Snapkit login web api?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, snapchat

I am attempting to use the snapkit login web api for a hybrid application. I have successfully been able to intercept the access token in the redirectURL. I was wondering if there was a way to get the users Bitmoji using this access_token and either the functions found in login.js or an http get call?

Api docs: https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/login-kit/#web

currently I have the access_token in a deeplinking function on my app.component.ts . I have attempted to push to a new page with the navController and passing in the access_token as a parameter, but this doesn't help when attempting to get the users information.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the Deeplinking where I intercept the access_token using myapp://settings-set/ as the URL redirect and attempt to push a new page with the matching url.

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav,{
        '/settings-set/:token': SettingsSetPage
      }).subscribe((match) => {
        // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
        // match.$args - the args passed in the link
        // match.$link - the full link data

        this.nav.push(SettingsSetPage, {
          args: match
        });
        console.log('Successfully matched route', match.$args);
      },
      (nomatch) => {
        // nomatch.$link - the full link data
        console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
      });
    });

  }
```

In the setting-set page I recieve the parameter using:

```
this.args = navParams.get('args');

console.log("this is args", JSON.stringify(this.args));
```

but don't know how to use the information to get the users information

Answer (score 2):

The Bitmoji API can be very confusing at times. I suggest using Passport, a Node JS tool for OAuth, along with the Ionic framework. Snapchat has a [guide](https://github.com/Snapchat/passport-snapchat#how-do-i-obtain-a-user-profile-with-specific-fields) that explains how to grab specific fields, such as user name and Bitmoji avatar, from a user's Snapchat profile using passport. You can follow [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-an-ionic-application-with-a-nodejs-backend/) tutorial to learn how to integrate Node JS into your existing ionic app.

So in conclusion, try following these steps:

1. Integrate Node JS into your existing ionic app
2. Install Passport and follow Snapchat's guide for obtaining specific fields from the user's profile

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like Mora said you can use passport which will make your life easier. We also have a sample passport app running [here](https://github.com/Snapchat/express-4.x-passport-snapchat-example):

From the context you provided it seems like you have generated the `code` and not the `access_token`. After you get the code from the redirect url, you need to use the code to generate the access token. Check section 2.5 [here](https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/login-kit/#web).

Once you have the access token you can use that to request information. The crux of this lies in setting the "scope" correctly. To get the Bitmoji avatar make sure you set your scope to this at the very least:

```
var scope = ['https://auth.snapchat.com/oauth2/api/user.bitmoji.avatar'];
```

Hope this helps!